# redirect problem after deploying on Netlify

Tags: reactjs, redirect, build, netlify

This is my redirectUri at development mode and works fine at localhost

After deployment I didn't thought about redirection problem and the first time I logged in my app, it tried to redirect me to localhost

I looked at netlify docs and add this netlify.toml config file

[image]

I pushed the changes on gitHub but the app still tries to redirect at localhost

Does anyone know how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the redirectUri from spotify's dashboard to https://fervent-mccarthy-b9cf5a.netlify.app/ and now it works